# On Energy and its existence

Tags: energy

The question is simple:

> Does the Energy exists?

As a student, I have thought about this since along time (approximatly 2 o 3 years, when I began to study). Now I want to know if there is an experiment, book, paper (hypothesis), etc. that try to provide an *approch Materialistic of the Energy*.

Comment: What does it mean for energy to exist?  It is an extremely useful concept for understanding physical systems, but what are your criteria for "existence"?

Comment: Energy in physics performs a similar conceptual role to money in accounting, and numbers in mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Exist" is an existential philosophical question.

Physics is the discipline that models observations and **measurements** with mathematics so that it can describe data, and so as to also have a predictive tool for future data. Physics mathematical models need extra axioms to the mathematical ones, in order to pick up those mathematical solutions that describe the data.

Measurements means the axiomatically defined variables: [Time, meter, second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_measurement), [mass.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass)

If they exist, and they do because we define them all through the history of mankind, then energy exists  also as a function of these variables.